# Plugin not detected by safari 5

Tags: plugins, safari, npapi, npruntime

My npruntime plugin works perfectly fine with FF 3.6+,chrome and opera.
but safari 5 does not detect my plugin at all.I already have registry entries pointing to 
a valid location for my plugin and with appropriate mime types.
surprisingly it works on safari 3 only ( not working on safari 4 even)
can some please let me know if there is anything specific i should be doing to get my plugin detected by safari 4,5 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a description set? The one time I had that issue using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) it turned out to be that I had an empty value for plugin description.

Comment: I seem to be having almost everything... Things are working fine on refox 3.6+,chrome,opera and even for safari 3...........Safari 4 and higher aren't detecting my plugin ....how can i go about debugging this ??

Comment: did you check what I told you to check? You make no reference to it.

Comment: Hi Taxilian, sorry for late reply. Yes,I did check everything related to that.Its not working somehow :(

Comment: At that point, then, I'd have to look at it; you might try using FireBreath and see if you can make a FB plugin work, then compare the differences.